# Is there a way to run PHP version 5.4 w/ the latest MAMP version

Tags: php, mamp

I have the latest version of MAMP installed but i want it to run PHP version 5.4.

That version is included in the MAMP file dir. It is located…
-> bin/php/php5.4.42

but in the preferences pane there are only 2 PHP version options: 5.6.10 and 7

I want to do this a part of troubleshooting. i have a Drupal install and am getting the dreaded ‘White Screen of Death’. I’m trying anything and everything to get it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAMP lets you choose from the last two versions of PHP installed in bin/php. If you want to use 5.4.42, just leave this folder and another one of your choice inside this directory (move the others somewhere else so you have a copy, just in case). When you restart MAMP you'll be able to choose your preferred PHP version in the Preferences.
You can download more versions at https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to use other localwebserver called Ampps, and after installing it you can choose the version you want by the simple interface it provide.
You click on PHP ==> Change PHP version, and it will show you versions from 5.3 to 7.0.
Here is the link: http://www.ampps.com/
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome TopTomato , I'm glad this helped you.